# How to avoid different gaps between bars in matplotlib hist?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have array in which each item can be one of 5 values (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`). I would like display histogram of these values:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

values = ["D", "E", "A", "E", "B", "C", "A", "A", "D", "E"]
plt.hist(values)
```

However, there is large gap between 2nd and 3rd bar:

[image]

Is there any way to ensure that the gaps between the columns are the same size (regardless of the number of columns)?

Comment: It's a histogram, so I guess the number of intervals needs to be set to the total number -1.`plt.hist(values, bins=4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I have never tried to do a histogram with strings. I'm not quite sure how it *almost* work.

Even though it's a bit more wordy, I would rather rely on counting the number of occurences and using `bar()` to plot the result:

```
values = ["D", "E", "A", "E", "B", "C", "A", "A", "D", "E"]
val,count = np.unique(values, return_counts=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x=range(len(val)), height=count)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(val)))
ax.set_xticklabels(val)
```

[image]